# RADIUS module for java servlet container

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, containers, radius

Is there any solution for java servlet containers like mod_auth_dradius for Apache.

The idea is to authenticate users using RADIUS-server to get access to some part of the site hosted by a java servlet container.

Answer (score 3):

Not as far as I know, I too encountered this same issue looking for a tomcat module. We worked around it, by implementing our own radius client module (using JRadius) which communicates with a FreeRadius server to authenticate the user and return a user role in the Filter-Id attribute. We then use the returned role as an index into our internal database to retrieve a list of permitted actions for that role. If the requested user action is in the permission list defined for their role, then our client module returns authorization success to the main application.

Hope that provides some ideas for an alternative.

Kate.